# Cobol programs to run/release jobs in IBM Workload Scheduler for z/OS (TWSz)

Tags: cobol, mainframe, workload-scheduler

Is PIF the correct method? API seems more on datastore maintenance and manipulation. Are there some samples in Cobol for job run/release. Only found EQQPIFJC that does manipulate JCL variables but none on job release/run.

Answer (score 1):

PIF is the right interface to be used for integration with native z/OS programs, written in many languages, including COBOL.

EQQPIFJC is a sample program written in COBOL that show how to call PIF from COBOL. This is the only COBOL PIF sample provided by TWSz, but it doesn't mean this is the only scenario that can be implemented.

The full PIF documentation is available in the [TWSz Developer's Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRULV_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/zos/src_pif/eqqn1proginterface.htm).

PIF can be used to make any change and action on the definitions and to the plan. e.g. to submit a job stream (Occurrence) use an INSERT CPOC, to take actions on a job in the plan use MODIFY CPOP.

If you want to run the same scenarios in a batch instead from COBOL, also look at [WAPL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRULV_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/zos/src_wapl/eqqw1mst_welcome.html) that provides all PIF scenarios and more via simple scripting.